# Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. React native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a function fundBalance action function get called and inside of this function there and api call and after the api call resolved and i call the handleFundBalanceSuccess this error happens "Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. React native"

```
    export function fundBalance(navigation) {
        return async (dispatch) => {
            dispatch({
                type: Fund_Balance_START
            })
            let response = await api.Fund_Balance(),
                responseJson = await response.json();
            if(response.status == 200){
                dispatch(handleFundBalanceSuccess(responseJson, navigation, dispatch)) // this line return Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions
            }
        }
    }
```

and the handleFundBalanceSuccess

```
handleFundBalanceSuccess = (response, navigation, dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: Fund_Balance_SUCESS,
    })
    navigation.navigate('MessageScreen', {
        title: 'Success',
        description: response.status,
        doneClick: this.fundBalanceOrCashOutSuccessAction.bind(this, navigation),
    })
}
```

Comment: remove dispatch(handle....) to handleFundBalanceSuccess(responseJson, navigation, dispatch)

Answer (score 1):

For dispatching functions, you would need `redux-thunk` middleware.
Without this middleware, dispatch would only expect object parameters.

For more details on redux-thunk and how to implement it, you can check here -
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#motivation

However, in this case, you don't need to dispatch the function. Just calling the function would solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `handleFundBalanceSuccess` method you need to return plain object. For example this one in your case:

```
handleFundBalanceSuccess = (response, navigation, dispatch) => {
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
  return {
   type: Fund_Balance_SUCESS,
  };
}
```